# How to see that the inverse limit and group completion are isomorphic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding a proof from Lang on why the completion and the inverse limit $\displaystyle \lim_{\longleftarrow}\ G/H_r$ are isomorphic. Here $\{H_r\}$ is a sequence of normal subgroups in $G$ with $H_r\supset H_{r+1}$ for all $r$.

> **Theorem 10.1** The completion and the inverse limit $\displaystyle \lim_{\longleftarrow}\ G/H_r$ are isomorphic under natural mappings.
>
> Proof. We give the maps. Let $x=\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence. Given $r$, for all $n$ sufficiently large, by the definition of Cauchy sequence, the class of $x_n\mod H_r$ is independent of $n$. Let this class be $x(r)$. Then the sequence $(x(1),x(2),\dots)$ defines an element of the inverse limit. Conversely, given an element $(\bar{x_1},\bar{x_2},\dots)$ of the inverse limit, with $\bar{x_n}\in G/H_n$, let $x_n$ be a representative in $G$. Then the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy. We leave to the reader to verify that the maps we have defined are inverse isomorphisms between the completion and the inverse limit.

I want to see if I'm understanding this correctly (unlikely). So $x(r)$ is the class of all elements $y\in G$ such that $x_ny^{-1}\in H_r$? Then $(x(1),x(2),\dots)$ is an element if the inverse limit as for $n\geq m$, we can take $f^n_m\colon G/H_n\to G/H_m$ to be the canonical homomorphism such that $\bar{x_n}$ in $G/H_n$ maps to $\bar{x_n}=\bar{x_m}$ in $G/H_m$ since $H_m\supset H_n$?

Also, to see that $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy from $(\bar{x_1},\bar{x_2},\dots)$, I know that $f^n_m(\bar{x_n})=\bar{x_m}$ by definition of the inverse limit, so $\bar{x_n}=\bar{x_m}$ in $G/H_m$, so $\overline{x_nx_m^{-1}}=\bar{e}\in G/H_m$, so $x_nx_m^{-1}\in H_m$. Then given any $H_r$, for $n,m\geq r$, $x_nx_m^{-1}\in H_m\subset H_r$, and $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy?

But then how exactly are the two maps inverses? I didn't quite understand the maps since Lang seems to map a Cauchy sequences $\{x_n\}$ to an element of the inverse limit, but the completion consists of equivalence classes mod the null sequences, so actual Cauchy sequences aren't even elements of the completion $C/C_0$?

Thank you for any clarifying details. I've been struggling to flesh this out for a while.

Comment: Let $C$ be the group of Cauchy sequences in $G$. He's defining a homomorphism $C \to \varprojlim G/H_r$ which kills off the null sequences: if $\{x_n\}$ is a null sequence then for each $r$ there is some $N$ such that $n \geqq N$ implies $x_n \in H_r$, so $x(r)$ is the identity. Hence we get a map on the quotient.

Comment: @Dylan, are you saying the isomorphism follows from the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: I'm just describing how he's getting a map on the completion by defining a map on the Cauchy sequences.

Comment: @Dylan, thanks. So when $\{x_n\}$ is a null sequence, $x(r)=\bar{e}$ since $x_ne^{-1}\in H_r$. Sorry, was my interpretation of $x(r)$ in the main question correct? I had a hard time understanding what $x_n\mod H_r$ means, since I'm mostly used to seeing this applied to integers.

Comment: @yunone So what exactly does $x_n$mod$H_r$ mean? Sorry for bumping an old q btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you want to check both compositions. Let's try to do one of them.

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence in $G$. We send this to the sequence $(x(n))$ in the prescribed manner. To get back to the completion, for each $n$ we pick a representative $y_n$ of $x(n)$ in $G$. We need to show that $\{x_n\}$ and $\{y_n\}$ are equal in the completion, i.e. that $\{x_ny_n^{-1}\}$ is a null sequence. To verify this, fix an $r$. There is an $N \geqq r$ such that $n, m \geqq N$ implies $x_nx_m^{-1} \in H_r$.

Fixing an arbitrary $n \geqq N$, there is an $m \geqq N$ such that $x_mH_n = x(n)$. So
$$
f^n_r(x_mH_n) = x_mH_r = f^n_r(x(n)).
$$
From the Cauchy condition, we have $x_mH_r = x_nH_r$. And $y_nH_n = x(n)$ implies
$$
f^n_r(y_nH_n) = y_nH_r = f^n_r(x(n)).
$$
Thus $x_nH_r = y_nH_r$ for $n \geqq N$, so $\{x_ny_n^{-1}\}$ is indeed a null sequence.

Comment: Thanks Dylan, I think I follow this argument. Also, did you mean to say $x_m\equiv x(n)\mod H_r$, in the second to last line?

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't mean to second guess you. I was just confused on how an element $x_n$ of $G$ can be equivalent to a whole congruence class $x(n)$ in $G/H_r$. I just thought I would have $x_m\equiv x(n)$ since $x_nx_m^{-1}\in H_r$, which I assumed was how $x(r)$ was characterized. I haven't yet proved how things are well-defined; I was mostly hoping to see how the two maps were inverses, and hence bijective. I'll see if I can see this more clearly in the morning.

Comment: @yunone It's quite alright. I just meant that $x(n)$ is $x_m$ for $m$ very large, so the Cauchy condition is going to make the images of these in $G/H_r$ equal.

Comment: I think I see the other direction. So I want to map from the inverse limit to the completion and back. If $(\bar{x_1},\bar{x_2},\dots)$ is in the inverse limit, then it maps to a Cauchy sequence $\{x_n\}$. Mapping back gives $(x(1),x(2),\dots)$. But $x(n)=\bar{x_n}$ since they are both the class of $x_n\mod H_r$. So $(\bar{x_1},\bar{x_2},\dots)=(x(1),x(2),\dots)$ which shows the composition on the inverse limit is the identity? If you have time to expand like you mentioned above, that'd be great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see your most recent comment while writing my own above. I understand your answer better now, but why do we want that $\{x_ny_n^{-1}\}$ is a null sequence? Don't we just want that the composition maps a sequence back to itself to see it is the identity?

Comment: Ah, because that would prove that they're equal in $C/C_0$, which is what I actually want to show is isomorphic to the inverse limit?

Comment: Thanks for adding that to your answer. Talking about the other direction sounds quite helpful. I'm pretty busy this weekend, but I'm sure we'll both be online sometime next week so I'll try to set up a chat room for questions I have. Thanks very much for the time you've put into this.